# Can any one tell what is the 4th line in  this function doing!

Tags: c++

```
size_t hash(const std::string data) {
    size_t h(0);
    for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++){
        h = (h << (31-i) ^ (h >> i) ^ data[i]);
    }
    h = h%hashsize;
    return h;
}
```

Comment: Well, I'd say it has a bug. Seeing that "31" and size_t used together means it's probably not mixing the way it was intended to mix.

Comment: That's going to require a lot of pencil and paper work.  What is the context of the function call?

Comment: i found this somewhere in the net and dont understand this `h = (h << (31-i) ^ (h >> i) ^ data[i]);
`

Comment: @ohmantics: Yep. It should probably do something with sizeof(size_t) and CHAR_BIT.

Comment: @zombie : If that part, specifically, is what you're confused about, then your question title is extremely poorly worded.

Comment: See http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx and the section on Rotating Hash. You may want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or as well.

Comment: @zombie: Look at it. It's taking some of the high bits and the low bits of the previous hash value and the data value to XOR together to make a new hash value. Hash values need to be as unique as possible and this looks like a decent way to get one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hash function for `std::string`, ostensibly suitable for TR1 and C++11's [`std::unordered_map<>`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/unordered_map/start), [`std::unordered_set<>`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/unordered_set/start), etc. I.e., it attempts to create an as-unique-as-possible `size_t` value for the given `std::string` for use in hash tables.

That being said, it's a poor hash function. Any standard library implementation that comes with `unordered_map<>`, `unordered_set<>`, etc. will come with built-in hash functions for standard library strings that have better implementations than this one.

**EDIT:** (In response to comment) `<<` is bitwise shift left, `>>` is bitwise shift right, and `^` is bitwise XOR, all of which are briefly discussed in this wikipedia entry: [Bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: so ..what you mean to say is it will create unique unsigned integer for that string!am i right?

Comment: @zombie : Not unique, but as-unique-as-possible -- there are too many possible string values to produce a truly-unique integer for each one given only 32/64 bits of storage (on most platforms). But yes, that's the idea.